# How to enable page dragging / scrolling on MGWT buttons?

Tags: mgwt

I have an MGWT app with a lot of buttons on a scrollable page (FlowPanel in an MGWT ScrollPanel).  Since the buttons use the full page width I'm nearly unable to scroll down, because all MGWT buttons capture the drag events.

How to prevent the buttons from doing this?

If I'm using normal GWT buttons I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is impossible with MGWT 2.0.0.  It's not possible to extend the `Button` class and replace the `TouchHandler` with an own one since unfortunately the `TouchHandler` is only accessible via a private field and therefore unaccessible from any subclass.

A fixed this bug and also the inheritance issue in the following pull request:
https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt/pull/264